# How to make shell for git clone using for loop

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell

I want to make git clone with for loop. So I made a shell as below.

```
mss=("company","fruit","car")

for ms in "${mss[@]}" ; do
        git clone https://github.com/test/$ms
        yarn // to install node_module of each repository
done
```

But when I run this shell, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell arrays don't have commas in them - the elements are separated by whitespace:

```
mss=("company" "fruit" "car")
```